# Android java update same arrays objects in all classes

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a arraylist in my fragment class. I pass the array to the adapter. After the adapter, I pass the array to another fragment. Now in the current fragment, I change a value of the array object. I want this change to change in the first fragment array. How is this possible?

look at the example code:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    ArrayList<Model> array = new ArrayList<>();
    // send array to Adapter
}

public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<Model> array = new ArrayList<>();
    array.addAll(getArrayFromFragment1); // use this.array = getArrayFromFragment1 // I don't want to use (this) 
    // send array to Fragment2
}

public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {
    ArrayList<Model> array = new ArrayList<>();
    array.addAll(getArrayFromAdapter); // use this.array = getArrayFromAdapter // I don't want to use (this)
    // NOW! update object value from array --> array.get(10).setUserPhoneNumber(987654321)
    // i need update automatically Fragment1 array object 10 UserPhoneNumber
}
```

In instagram app:

`fragment 1 --> gragment 2 --> explore tab --> fragment 3 like one post --> back to fragment 1 same post liked. how do this relations?`

Answer (score 1):

I would use a separate class with a static ArrayList so you only need to use a single source for the data and can read it from any class/fragment.

```
public class StaticUtils {
    public static ArrayList<Model> models = new ArrayList<>();
    //or make it private and add static getter/setter methods here
}

public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {
    StaticUtils.models.get(10).setUserPhoneNumber(987654321)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Does static use cause memory problems?

Comment: And I use multiple arrays in the app. I have 20 fragments. And there are separate arrays in each. Isn't that a problem?

Comment: If you're concerned with memory you can place these static arrays at the lowest level parent class of whatever classes are using them. That way they are only in memory when the classes that use them are instantiated. If the 20 arrays in each fragment are all copies of the same array like your example in the question, there won't be a problem and using a static array will make it easier to work with and reduce memory usage. But if they are separate arrays using different data then this solution won't work for you.